# selection sort on singly linked list

Tags: sorting, linked-list

my algorithm works...almost...for some reason the last two elements are in the wrong order after sorting. Also, the print statement does not show me that `first` moves to the right.

```
public static SLL sort(SLL list)
{
    SLLNode first = list.first ;
    SLLNode second ;

    while (first!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(first.data); // for seeing if first does move to the right
        second = first.succ ;
        while (second!=null)
        {
            if (second.data.compareTo(first.data)<0)
            {
                String temp = first.data ;
                first.data = second.data ;
                second.data = temp ;
            }
            second = second.succ ;
        }
        first = first.succ ;
    }
    return list ;
}
```

before sorting:  `FFF fff Hi AAA Bye Ciao`

after sorting:   `AAA Bye Ciao FFF Hi fff`

my print statement outputs `FFF` at first, then only `fff`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because ascii value of capitals is less than that of lowercase letters.

[image: ascii]

Comment: Use `compareToIgnoreCase` if you only plan on comparing String. Or, alternatively, use `System.String.Compare(stringA, stringB, true)`, the `bool` parameter tells the function if it should compare case-sensitive or not.

Comment: @N 1.1, thanks! any idea why the print statement doesn't give me what i expect?

Answer (score 0):

```
Also, the print statement does not show me that first moves to the right.
System.out.print(); // for seeing if first does move to the right
```

That print() statement just shows nothing.